# How do I use a Service Account with Google Admin SDK when an admin account address isn't known?

Tags: google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace

I am creating a service in the Google Apps marketplace which needs the ability to pull down a list of all user accounts in a Google Apps domain.  It appears that to use a Service Account with the Admin SDK, you must specify a "sub" (a user who you are acting on behalf of).

My code works just fine if you already know a domain admin's address to put in the "sub" field, since my OAuth token is accepted across the entire Google Apps domain.  However, this service doesn't know a domain admin's e-mail address, and I don't really want to ask the user for one and pin against it, because it might change without warning.

Does anyone know of a way to query the user directory without having to already know an admin e-mail address to "act as"?

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

PRIVATE_KEY = "privatekey.p12"
SERVICE_ACCOUNT = "(removed)@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly"

# Read in key file
key_file = file(PRIVATE_KEY, 'rb')
key = key_file.read()
key_file.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(service_account_name=SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
                                            private_key=key,
                                            scope=SCOPE,
                                            # What if I don't already know the
                                            # e-mail address of an admin?
                                            sub="an_admin@mattslifebytes.com")

# Authorize the httplib2.Http object
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)
service.users().list(domain="mattslifebytes.com",
                     fields="users(primaryEmail,thumbnailPhotoUrl)").execute()
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can not do that. In any case, you're getting the admin email when he visits your's page.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the administrator to login to your application once so you can retrieve their email address. You can check if this step has been completed and if not show the user a message that the application requires additional setup from the administrator.

Comment: I had considered this, but I wasn't planning to use Google as the primary authentication mechanism as the user management system is part of a larger architecture.